# How to apply branch A born from branch B to branch C (without applying B to C)?

Tags: git

I have these branches:

[image: git branch -a]

We well call them:

**M** : `master` →
**P** : `limpiezaPropiedades` →
**F** : `listaYFormularios`

**P** was created from **M**, and when I created **F** I had **P** checked out. However, these two branches are not related and I just recently realized what I did. So now I want to apply to **M** the commits in **F** without applying the ones in **P**.

I want to put the two branches "in the same level":

**M** : `master` →
**P** : `limpiezaPropiedades`

**M** : `master` →
**F** : `listaYFormularios`

How can I achieve this in the simplest way possible?

Comment: Both answers are what I needed. Had to mark as answer one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some potential solutions:

1). Cherry pick

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick limpiezaPropiedades..listaYFormularios   # Picks all commits in this range, not including the commit at 'limpiezaPropiedades'
```

2). Rebase

```
git checkout listaYFormularios
git rebase -i master
# Remove lines for commits that belong to limpiezaPropiedades
# BE CAREFUL, if you remove a commit that belongs to 'listaYFormularios', it will be lost and you will have to go through the reflog to recover it
```

Comment: I like that you recommended two ways. I was not aware one could cherry pick a range so easily by just naming branches.

Comment: Btwm I didn't understand your warning. What should I check before trying the second solution?

Comment: When you run `git rebase -i`, it will open an editor that lists all commits that will be applied during the rebase.  Because you only want commits from `listaYFormularios` and not from `limpiezaPropiedades`, you need to remove the lines that list commits from `limpiezaPropiedades`.  Any lines you delete will not be included as part of the rebase. So make sure that you don't accidentally remove commits from `listaYFormularios`, because if they are removed during the rebase they  will no longer be attached to a branch, and those changes will be lost the next time git runs its garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an interactive rebase to remove the commits you don't want in `F`. This is done by doing the following:

1. Make sure that you have `F` checked out.
2. Enter the command `git rebase -i master`.
3. This will open your configured editor with a list of all commits that are on branch `F` that aren't on branch `master`. This file is a script that the rebase command will replay after you have finished editing it. In this case, since all you want to do is to remove some commits from `F`, delete the lines representing the commits that are in `P` that you don't want in `F`.
4. Save and close the file. Git will then remove the commits you deleted from the file, and `F` will now be based on `master`.

Note that you should (probably) only do this if you haven't pushed `F` since this will cause commit hashes to change, and will cause other developers grief when they pull your branch.

For more information on rebasing, [Git - Rewriting History](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) has a pretty good overview.

Comment: Thank you! No, I didn't push neither of these branches. Thanks for the explanation.